# Obiaf Intel graphics drivers won't update - 404 not found

Tags: debian, drivers, crunchbang

Following up to my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100831/apt-get-update-wont-update-undo-apt-add-repository/100853#100853), I'm following a guide on how to get games to play on my linux computer. However, the guide specifically asks to run the command `apt-add-repository ppa:obiaf/intel-driver`, and the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

How can I make it so that the command, `apt-add-repository ppa:obiaf/intel-driver`, functions correctly?

(Note: I do have stable internet connection, so that is not a problem)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your connection. The files at the other end of those URLs are no longer available. If you put this URL in a web browser, you'll note the not found errors:

URL:

> http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources

Error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at ppa.launchpad.net Port 80
```

If you back that URL off a bit in your browser you'll notice which distros are available:

> http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/

- maverick/
- natty/
- oneiric/
- precise/
- quantal/
- raring/
- saucy/

I'd check to see what distro you're using and re-point to the correct one for your particular version.

Comment: It never would have been available. Wheezy is Debian and he is trying to use a Ubuntu PPA.

Comment: @jordanm - thanks I was trying to get him to realize that 8-). Notice I never said anything about Ubuntu, simply showing the method to triage one's own problems like this so that he and maybe others will notice this down the road and get a better understanding that the different distros are different.

Comment: Are you saying that these drivers are available only to Ubuntu?

Comment: @Patrick - no I'm saying the URLs that this user was attempting to access were no longer available. Someone had taken down the files or they moved on the web server that was serving them. On this server the only Ubuntu distros that are supported are in the list I posted. That's not to say that these drivers won't work on other distros, but these ones were only meant for consumption by Ubuntu distros.